# Facebook tab review is missing

Tags: facebook

The reviews tab is missing https://www.facebook.com/AlmogSPA

I need to add a reviews tab like here https://www.facebook.com/uniqueitworld/reviews?ref=page_internal

I have tried to change it to "local business" and to change address but it not worked

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not facebook support

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/AlmogSPA/reviews – unclear what you’re asking.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming or software development.

Answer (score 0):

You do have the `Reviews` tab in your page. Since there can only be about 4 tabs visible at a time, it is placed inside the `More` section. Click on `More` and then `Manage Tabs`. There you can rearrange your tabs and bring the `Reviews` tab towards the top.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is incorrect. The reviews tab seems to be not visible to the OP (in fact, I see now that they went with a 3rd party app to recover the ability to interact with them). However, the reviews are visible to the anyone but the page owner.

This seems to be a relatively common problem, with no answer from facebook. (See for example [this](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/community/question/?id=10104904941325147) post, (but there are hundreds of them)

Seems to be an ongoing problem with facebook that has never been addressed or solved.

Howerver, a few people have had success by adding/re-adding either an address or a business category to their page, but for most, this does not work (I refer you to the comments in the same link).

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do it is:
Go to settings
Go to general
Enable the reviews option
Have fun!